# JPA Hibernate is creating temporary tables for a simple update query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple query in my repository to increment number of comments for a post given the post object:

```
public interface PostsRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Post, Long>{

//...

@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Post p set p.numComments = p.numComments + 1 where p = :post")
void incrementNumComments(@Param("post") post obj);

//...
}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="posts")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "post_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Long id;
}
```

However, hibernate seems to be using a temporary table to execute the query. Here are the generated queries from the logs:

```
Hibernate: insert into HT_posts select pos0_.post_id as post_id from posts pos0_ where pos0_.s_id=?
Hibernate: update posts set num_comments=num_comments+1 where (post_id) IN (select post_id from HT_posts)
```

Is there a way to prevent Hibernate from using temporary tables for this query?

Thanks

Comment: I think the reason is in the annotation `@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)`

Comment: @Giovanni I suspected that as well, but I am unsure how to rectify if the annotation is the culprit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find details about [Multitable bulk operations](http://in.relation.to/2005/07/20/multitable-bulk-operations/).

As @Giovanni mentioned, this is because of the use of `InheritanceType.JOINED`.